# Set position in xslt if variable equals

Tags: xslt

Can you set the position of a particular item in a for-each loop if the value equals something? I tried the below example but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='name = "Dining"'>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()=1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            [Normal position]
        </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Dining will always appear at the top of the list and then the list will render as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided an example of your input XML, or shown exactly what you want to do with it, so I am guessing a bit. You could try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Dining"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Dining)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML:

```
<root>
  <Bathroom />
  <Dining />
  <Kitchen />
  <Bedroom />
</root>
```

It produces:

```
<root>
  <Dining />
  <Bathroom />
  <Kitchen />
  <Bedroom />
</root>
```